# TypeError at /account/ sequence item 1: expected a bytes-like object, NoneType found

Tags: django

I am trying to get a progress bar to load as per the instructions [here](https://github.com/czue/celery-progress).

At the moment this is my view.

```
def progress_view(request):
count_pag = 200
result = hello.tasks.my_task(8,request).delay(1)
context = {'task_id': result.task_id}
return render(request, 'display_progress.html', context={'task_id': result})
```

This is my tasks.py

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def my_task(self, seconds, request):
   progress_recorder = ProgressRecorder(self)
   result = 0
   for i in range(seconds):
      time.sleep(1)
      result += i
      progress_recorder.set_progress(i + 1, seconds)
   return result
```

There is no problem when i remove the 'request' input. But i need some sort of extra input into the function in order to do the processing i want. How to add extra inputs to the 'my_task' function without giving a traceback like below???

```
Traceback:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/alvintung/rndtwitr/hello/views.py" in account
22.             return progress_view(request)

File "/Users/alvintung/rndtwitr/hello/views.py" in progress_view
33.     result = hello.tasks.my_task(8,request).delay(1)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery.  
/local.py" in __call__
191.         return self._get_current_object()(*a, **kw)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/task.py" in __call__
375.             return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/alvintung/rndtwitr/hello/tasks.py" in my_task
27.         progress_recorder.set_progress(i + 1, seconds)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery_progress/backend.py" in set_progress
40.                 'description': description

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/task.py" in update_state
892.         self.backend.store_result(task_id, meta, state)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py" in store_result
322.                            request=request, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py" in _store_result
664.         self.set(self.get_key_for_task(task_id), self.encode(meta))

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py" in get_key_for_task
 570.             self.task_keyprefix, key_t(task_id), key_t(key),

Exception Type: TypeError at /account/
Exception Value: sequence item 1: expected a bytes-like object, NoneType found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call task function directly. To run it in a background you should use `delay()` and provide arguments there:

```
def progress_view(request):
    count_pag = 200
    result = hello.tasks.my_task.delay(8, request.POST.get("extra_data"))  # assuming POST body contains extra_data input
    context = {'task_id': result.task_id}
    return render(request, 'display_progress.html', context={'task_id': result})
```

Also note that arguments you are passing to celery task should be serializable. So you cannot pass full request object to the task. You shoud use requred data from POST body:

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def my_task(self, seconds, extra_data):
   print(extra_data) # data from request body
   progress_recorder = ProgressRecorder(self)
   result = 0
   for i in range(seconds):
      time.sleep(1)
      result += i
      progress_recorder.set_progress(i + 1, seconds)
   return result
```

Comment: As i said in my question, I am aware this version you posted works. But how can i pass added inputs into my_task, even if its just ints and strings? I am aware my code doesn't use them yet.

Comment: @user2353418 what exactly extra input you need? Data from `POST` request body?

Comment: i need an int and a string from POST request body.

Comment: TypeError: my_task() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Are you sure you did exactly the same? Probably you try to pass three arguments in view, but didn't add third argument in task. It should be like this: `def my_task(self, seconds, extra_data, extra_data2):`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208074/discussion-between-user2353418-and-neverwalkaloner).